# What causes a guava tree to have brown lines on leafes anddoesn't give flowers/fruits?

Tags: diseases, guavas, leaf

I'm helping a friend with a guava(strawberry guava) tree problem. In addition to what you see on the leafes, it doesn't give any fruit/flowers.

it's just finished the humid season. it grows in a pot in a house.

[image]

[image]